# How to set PS1 that make both git and conda can show in the bash?

Tags: bash, git, anaconda, ps1

My .bashrc:

```sh
# show a short way
shortwd() {
    num_dirs=3
    pwd_symbol="..."
    newPWD="${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
    if [ $(echo -n $newPWD | awk -F '/' '{print NF}') -gt $num_dirs ]; then
        newPWD=$(echo -n $newPWD | awk -F '/' '{print $1 "/.../" $(NF-1) "/" $(NF)}')
    fi
    echo -n $newPWD
}
# show git branch
git_branch() {
   git symbolic-ref HEAD --short
}

export PS1='\n$CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER\e[38;5;211m$(shortwd)\e[38;5;48m [$(git_branch)]\e[0m$'
```

now the bash look like:

> (base) /.../MyCode/python [master]$

but after I run `conda activate env` to switch my conda env.   It get a BUG that,whatever command I run ,there always show the current conda env name in the end of command output.like this:

> (base) /.../MyCode/python [master]$ls
>   code_study  keras  mxnet  my_tools  other  pyqt5  pytorch  qt_diankeyuan  test  windowsCode
>   (base)

[image]

If I want to make the conda env name do not always show in end of the each command output,what should I do?
[image]

Comment: unrelated, sorry, but what benefit do you get from setting PS1 to anything other than `$`?

Comment: @oguzismail Many people use the prompt to display context which they feel is relevant, like which host they are on (many people log in to many places and need to quickly find out where they are before saying `rm -rf /*`) or what they are in the middle of, as well as the time of day etc.

Comment: @manv Sure, thanks for the feedback; reopened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest letting Conda handle its own part of modifying `PS1` and use your nice custom bash functions for the other parts. For this, I would change the `PS1` to

```
export PS1='\e[38;5;211m$(shortwd)\e[38;5;48m [$(git_branch)]\e[0m$'
```

and move this to *before* the Conda-managed section of your `.bashrc`.  Next, set the Conda configuration variable `env_prompt` to what you want:

```
conda config --set env_prompt "\n({default_env}) "
```

You can read more about the templateable variables in the description `conda config --describe env_prompt`.

The only way this deviates from the behavior you defined is that when no envs are active you won't get the extra newline, but hopefully you can live with that. The other downside is that Conda only allows prepending.

---

As an aside, your `git_branch` function is going emit to `stderr` when not in a repo, so you may want to divert that so it doesn't hit your session. For example,

```bash
# show git branch                                                                                                                                      
git_branch() {
    git symbolic-ref HEAD --short 2> /dev/null
}
```

Comment: There is no "Conda-managed section" in my `.bashrc`

Comment: @rkedge, the relevant part of my `~/.bashrc` starts with `# >>> conda initialize >>>` , and has `__conda_setup` somewhere soon. It ends with `# <<< conda initialize <<<`. When I moved this after any `PS1` stuff in `~/.bashrc`, it fixed the problems I was having with my `$PS1`. You might want to look in `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or maybe even something like `~/.profile` or `~/.login`. If there's nothing there, you might have to look into `/etc/`, e.g. `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/profile`. `PS1` stuff _should_ be in `~/.bashrc` (maybe in `/etc/bashrc`, but it doesn't feel quite right).

Comment: would this work using zsh?

Comment: OK! It works ok for me , nice and simple